# how to solve this error in Eclipse Oxygen for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make script in Eclipse Oxygen for Android application but I am getting error in project, so any one can help me.

Code:- is uploaded in image.[image]
But on bolded lines I am getting error, if any one can help me.

Error:- The method setCapability(String, String) is undefined for the type DesiredCapabilities

Thank you in advance[image]